# How can I use css files in django?

Tags: python, css, django

I'm using a template with block tags to include a css file.

Unsure on how to manage css files, I put this in my urls.py:

```
url(r'style.css$','portal.views.css')
```

with this in my views

```
def css(request):
    return render_to_response('style.css')
```

When I use chrome's "inspect element" on any page that uses the template I can see all the css in the file, however nothing at works on the page itself. To test it I added

```
body 
 { 
   display:none; 
 }
```

But still no changes.

Do I need to render the response in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't serve static files (like css files) that way.
Django provides a specific solution for that, make sure you read the [complete and comprehensive documentation on that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).